# Scrolling UITableView crashes only in iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode3.2, ios-4.2

I recently upgraded to xCode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 . After this, the app crashes while scrolling the table which has text fields.

resignFirstResponder throws "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" and crashes the app.

The same code works perfect with earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: More info necessary. Post offending code and the exact error messages/stack traces.

Comment: it's hard to say anything without code. Add code where you putting values into sells.

Comment: What's causing your text fields to resign as first responders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
You should check your code for memory management.
I have also faced with problems, like code running on 3.2 but not on 4.2.
This is due to the fact that iOS 4.2 is more robust. Sometimes it happens that we are not using the proper coding methods, & it is running fine on 3.2.
But 4.2 is not accepting such mistakes.